# Swift: Change UIImageView based on IF

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to change a UIImageView based on what section of my app I am displaying.

In my view controller, this works to set the image:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

let imageName = "sectionOneBackground"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

However, if I wrap the image in an if like so:

```
var imageName = ""

if (section == "one") {
    imageName = "sectionOneBackground"
}

if (section == "two") {
    imageName = "sectionTwoBackground"
}

if (section == "three") {
    imageName = "sectionThreeBackground"
}
```

Then it just doesnt appear on the view. Am I missing someting entirely. Is there an easier way to change the background of a view without this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are used the imageview as instance , create your image view as global

Comment: Could I trouble you and ask to post that as an answer and show me how? I am a noob ya see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the Imageview an string name as global

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
 var imageView : UIImageView!
 var imageName : String!

}
```

on your viewdidload create the imageview as like

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    imageName = "sectionOneBackground"
    imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName)!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    view.addSubview(imageView)

}
```

**finally**

whenever you change the imageview name as

```
if (section == "one") {
imageName = "sectionOneBackground"
}

else if (section == "two") {
imageName = "sectionTwoBackground"
}

else if (section == "three") {
imageName = "sectionThreeBackground"
}
 imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

**set the final Image name to your image view**

```
  imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```